# Get Max and Min of 2 Columns SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query is the final part of a store procedure that manages to show me the results in this way:

```
;with final_comparativo as (
                    select s.CeEmplazamiento, avg(s.Totales) TotalGeneral , s2.TotGral, @Mes as Mes
                    from tmpSemanas s
                        cross join ( select avg(Totales) TotGral from tmpSemanas s2 where Totales >0) s2
                    group by s.CeEmplazamiento , s2.TotGral
            union all
                    select ss.CeEmplazamiento, avg(ss.Totales) TotalGeneral , ss2.TotGral, @Mes_comparar as Mes
                    from tmpSemanas_comparar ss
                        cross join ( select avg(Totales) TotGral from tmpSemanas_comparar ss2 where Totales >0) ss2
                    group by ss.CeEmplazamiento , ss2.TotGral
        )                       


        --insert #tmpDatos
        , maximo_minimo as (
            select CeEmplazamiento,
                max(case when Mes  = @Mes then TotalGeneral else 0 end) as Mes_actual,
                max(case when Mes  = @Mes_comparar then TotalGeneral else 0 end) as Mes_comparar
            from final_comparativo
            where TotalGeneral <> 0
            group by CeEmplazamiento    
            )

            select * from maximo_minimo
            drop table #tmpDatos
```

This is the current result table

```
CeEmplazamiento Month_current Month_compare
Celaya          76.500000       75.600000
Coecillo        79.000000       79.800000
Irapuato        77.500000       75.400000
León Sur        85.750000       87.600000
Oriente León    86.250000       85.200000
```

The store procedure asks you for 2 arguments corresponding to month_current (month of origin) month_compare (against which month you want to compare the month_current) so it is already a final calculation. But my problem lies in the following, I want this table to take the maximum and minimum of the current month and likewise for the column "Month_compare", I hope I have explained. More briefly, I would like it to remain this way.

```
CeEmplazamiento       Month_current Month_compare
Leon Sur              85.75        87.60
Celaya                76.50         null
Irapuato               null        75.40
```

As far as you can tell, it is not the same amount for all CeEsmplazamiento, those that are not in the current Month, are not shown but are taken into account for a graphic that is being done. I hope you can help me

Comment: why is Irapuato  null at Mes_Actual? i thought you are only after of Mes_comparar being Min and Max

Comment: That data is neither the maximum nor the mínimum in  "mes_actual", but it is the minimum in the mes_comparar

Comment: suggestion, you will have to translate your columns to english and clearly state what you need there.

Comment: You're all right! Sorry! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smth like this:

```
    declare @t table(CeEmplazamiento varchar(100),  Month_current money, Month_compare money);
    insert into @t values
    ('Celaya',          76.500000,       75.600000),
    ('Coecillo',        79.000000,       79.800000),
    ('Irapuato',        77.500000,       75.400000),
    ('León Sur',        85.750000,       87.600000),
    ('Oriente León',    86.250000,       85.200000);

    with cte1 as
    (
    select top 1 CeEmplazamiento, Month_current, null as Month_compare
    from @t 
    order by  Month_current asc
    )

    ,cte2 as
    (
    select top 1 CeEmplazamiento, Month_current, null as Month_compare
    from @t 
    order by  Month_current desc
    )

    ,cte3 as
    (
    select top 1 CeEmplazamiento, null as Month_current, Month_compare
    from @t 
    order by  Month_compare asc
    )

    ,cte4 as
    (
    select top 1 CeEmplazamiento, null as Month_current, Month_compare
    from @t 
    order by  Month_compare desc
    )

    select *
    from cte1 
    union all
    select *
    from cte2
    union all
    select *
    from cte3 
    union all
    select *
    from cte4
```